# Performing mathematical operations on attribute value

Tags: javascript

I am attempting to perform mathematical operations with JavaScript on values obtained from an attribute. The attribute is created via a PHP loop. I will give an example of one of the html tags containing the attributes, but keep in mind that there are many of these tags which contain unique attribute values.

**The HTML:**

```
<a href="secondary_imgs.php..." mwidth="593"></a>
```

**The JavaScript(jQuery):**

```
    $("a[href^='secondary_imgs.php']").click(function(){
        var pageWidth = $(window).width();
        var maxshadowWidth = (Math.floor(pageWidth * 0.91808874)) - 2;
        var mWidth = $(this).attr("mwidth");
        var maxSecondaryWidth = mWidth + 60;
        alert (maxSecondaryWidth);
        if(maxSecondaryWidth <= maxshadowWidth) {
            var shadowWidth = maxSecondaryWidth;
        } else {
            var shadowWidth = maxshadowWidth;
        }
        var shadowboxrel = 'shadowbox;width=' + shadowWidth;
        $(this).attr('rel', shadowboxrel);
```

The operation doesn't seem to be working, and I have a feeling it has to do with my lack of experience using mathematical operations in javascript. In this case, I think something is wrong with my method of using the attribute value, *in* the mathematical operation.

For example, the above `width` attribute is defined as `593`. I define the `maxSecondaryWidth` as `mWidth + 60`. I fired an alert to see what value I was getting. It should have been shown as `653`, yet the value that is 'alerted' is `59360`. Obviously I don't understand how to add, as the `+` is concatenating the two values, as opposed to adding them together. Could it have to do with needing to transform the attribute value from a string into an integer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to convert to a number using [`parseInt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt), otherwise `+` will do string concatenation:

```
var mWidth = parseInt($(this).attr("mwidth"), 10);
```

If the attribute can also be a float, use [`parseFloat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat) instead of `parseInt()`.

Comment: Thanks. I feel kinda like an idiot. I figured it out right after I submitted the question. Your answer is much more informative though. Thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

Do this to make sure `mwidth` is a number:

```
var mWidth = parseInt($(this).attr("mwidth"), 10);
```

Otherwise, `+` will perform a string concatenation. Alternatively, if you need `mwidth` to be a floating point number, do this:

```
var mWidth = parseFloat($(this).attr("mwidth"));
```

Comment: why not !isNaN(mWidth) then parseInt?

Comment: @JohnJohnGa - What would that do?

Comment: Because the value returned from `attr` will always be a string. Also, `isNaN` only checks if an object is `NaN`, which is a special value. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN

Answer (score 1):

You can do a couple things:

```
parseInt(mWidth, 10); // int
parseFloat(mWidth); // float
Number(mWidth); // number
```

otherwise javascript will believe it's a string.

Some less common conversions:

```
mWidth | 0; // int (javascript bitwise operations are 32-bit signed intergers)
+mWidth; // force Number
```

Answer (score 0):

i think that you must do something safer (as it is always better);
You should check if it is a number or not:
DOM:

```
<a href="secondary_imgs.php..." mwidth="593"></a>
<a href="secondary_imgs.php..." mwidth="93"></a>
<a href="secondary_imgs.php..." mwidth="ze"></a>
<a href="secondary_imgs.php..." mwidth="5d93"></a>
<a href="secondary_imgs.php..." mwidth="593"></a>
<a href="secondary_imgs.php..." mwidth="593"></a>
```

JS:

```
$("a[mwidth]").each(function(){
    var $attr = $(this).attr('mwidth');
    if(!isNaN($attr)){
        sum += (parseInt($attr));
    }
});
```

If you remove the condition the results will be `NaN`

Take a look at : http://jsfiddle.net/zVwYB/